# Text get above on the other text using "\r" in php in make a progress line

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I have this problem when using `\r` to create a simple Progress line with PHP.

This is example code looks like my real one but its too big to write it here.

```
$percent = 0;
for($i=0; $i<=1000000000; $i++){ //big number to take time looping and testing
    if( ($i % 10000000) == 0 ){ //thats mean each one percent do something
        echo "This is just a simple text\n Progress: $percent% just a simple progress line with php \r";
        $percent++;
    }
}
```

Here Output look like this.

```
   php file.php
This is just a simple text
This is just a simple texte progress line with php 
This is just a simple texte progress line with php 
This is just a simple texte progress line with php 
This is just a simple texte progress line with php 
This is just a simple texte progress line with php 
^Crogress: 5% just a simple progress line with php
```

But i want the output to be like this.

```
    php file.php
This is just a simple text
This is just a simple text
This is just a simple text
This is just a simple text
This is just a simple text
This is just a simple text
^Crogress: 5% just a simple progress line with php
```

Using `sleep(1);` Doesn't help too.

All the problem is that the progress line text `Progress: 5% just a simple progress line with php` get above on the other text.

Comment: You just can't, \r comes back to the start of the line, the next line start there, so your first part before the \n is printed on what already exists.

Comment: Carriage return (`\r`) takes you to the beginning of your current line. If you want to write the progress to another line at the bottom of the screen, I would imagine that you would need to use a library like ncurses (http://php.net/manual/en/intro.ncurses.php)

Comment: @Tensibai Thanks for replying, but what might help to solve this problem? any ideas?

Comment: @MartinCook Thanks, i will take a look at it.

Comment: If you want the progress line to be on one line, you have to remove what's overwriting it, so get rid of `This is just a simple text\n`. If the progress can be written on multiple lines, change the `\r` to `\n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just can't, \r comes back to the start of the line. The next echo start there, so your first part `This is just a simple text` is printed on what already exists.

If you want to clear up the remaining text, add spaces after text to overwrite the rest of `Progress: $percent% just a simple progress line with php`

Something like this should do:

`echo "This is just a simple text                                 \nProgress: $percent% just a simple progress line with php\r";`

This is quite complex if you change the second text so a better approach would be something like this (untested):

```
$percent = 0;
for($i=0; $i<=1000000000; $i++){ //big number to take time looping and testing
    if( ($i % 10000000) == 0 ){ //thats mean each one percent do something
        $first_line = "This is just a simple text";
        $second_line = "Progress: $percent% just a simple progress line with php\r";
        $diff = strlen($second_line) - strlen($first_line);
        echo $first_line.str_repeat(' ',$diff)."\n".$second_line;
        $percent++;
    }
}
```

The idea is to create the echo output with the addition of enough spaces to cover the second line on each iteration. Using two variables and their length allow to compute this difference and then using str_repeat allow to create the corret number of spaces.

Comment: +1 for spaces idea, but this isn't the whole answer because there is spaces in sensitive text, is there another way?

Comment: I don't get your comment, what is in the text is not a problem, a space is a character as others when counting the lengths of a string.

Comment: sorry for not asking clear, but what i mean when you copy this output text from CLI will copied with spaces.

Comment: Of course yes, but usually you don't print lines in a loop like this for a progress indicator, your just print the progress line and print the static line before the loop. If your question doesn't reflect your real need, ask another one with the real case ?

Comment: no the real code is like this 100% but rather than `This is just a simple text` i have a real text that might have info with spaces,

Comment: @IrisTako And ? I don't get what you're after, `This is just a simple text` has spaces. If there's another use of the output text, then maybe you should print it only after (and just print the progress while creating the output)

Comment: @IrisTako I've edited the code, my newline was misplaced to get a proper output.

Comment: Thanks, its work like a charm. In my case adding tabs will be easy to remove (my real code), but again Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you add some white space at the end of the first string, it will write over the second one, like this:

```
 $percent = 0;
 for($i=0; $i<=1000000000; $i++){ //big number to take time looping and testing
     if( ($i % 10000000) == 0 ){ //thats mean each one percent do something
         echo "This is just a simple text                                \n";
         echo "Progress: $percent% just a simple progress line with php \r";
         $percent++;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `\n` to `\r` and it will come out as you expect it too.

`echo "This is just a simple text\rProgress: {$percent}%\r";`

Here's a fiddle to see what the output of the above:
https://www.tehplayground.com/2Cst7KcFlOsdsjfN

Comment: Absolutely no need to enclose the variable in `{}` the echo works fine as it is. Did you try it?

Comment: Apologies, re-edited but left in the brackets anyway as I prefer it readability wise.

Comment: This is not what the OP is after at all (or it is the fiddle rendering not giving the expected results)